# Join syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

Please suggest me how to play with Join in javascript.
My Code

```
var multiTokenQuery = value.join(',');
    submitted.set('multiTokenQuery', multiTokenQuery);

alert(multiTokenQuery);
```

the above code shows `(abc,bcd)` but I want it in `('abc','bcd')` I mean I need single qoutes on the values ...
Please Help

Comment: What is `value`? What do you need the apostrophes for?

Comment: Why do you *need* single quotes? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Please check my answer I have elaborated my problem ...

Comment: @user3332404: You better should [edit] your question instead of posting an answer…

Answer (score 1):

You'd like to use the following instead to get your quotes.

```
var value = ['test','sample','example'];
var multiTokenQuery = "'" + value.join("','") + "'";

alert(multiTokenQuery);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FJUJ9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Change the glue in the bits:

```
var multiTokenQuery = value != null && value.length > 0 ? "'" + value.join("','") + "'" : value;
```

Comment: Thanks @Candide for your quick responce ..please chk my my post I have explained my problem hope you guys can suggest me something as I am new to java...

Comment: @user3332404 It seems you're new to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you post your answer below, as another question. If you switch the context of your original question too much, well, everyone will have to revise their answers, and it's not nice for all involved.